# Laravel 5.4, Cancel subscription gives error

Tags: laravel, braintree

I have this form:

```
<form action="{{route('subscription.cancel')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <button type="submit">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/subscription/cancel', 'SubscriptionController@cancel')->name('subscription.cancel');
```

SubscriptionController:

```
public function cancel(Request $request){
// dd($request->user()->subscription('main'));  //finds the right subscription in db
   $request->user()->subscription('main')->cancel();
   return redirect()->route('subscription.index');
}
```

DB:

id  - 7 
user_id - 1
name  - main
braintree_id - g4wqmw  
 
braintree_plan  - pro
quantity - 1    
trial_ends_at and ends_at are NULL
created_at - 2017-10-27 15:57:39
updated_at - 2017-10-27 15:58:23

Subscription model has only $fillable.

When I try to cancel subscription, I get this error: subscription with id g4wqmw not found. I can't find any solution.

Comment: Because its braintree_id not id. Paste whole error and functions in model.

Answer (score 2):

You should check in your query that you are actually asking for `braintree_id` and not `id`, cause your model `id` is `7` and your `braintree_id` is the one which is `g4wqmw`.
Cheers.